# MySQL Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

A little help please! I really don't know what's going on here already. I have read a lot about this but there just seems to be nothing I can find wrong with this query:

```
INSERT INTO clients (water_bill_doc_url) VALUES ('client-uploads/01/water_bill.png') WHERE `client_id` = '74'
```

but still I keep getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `client_id` = '74'' at line 1
```

if it helps, this `clients` table is InnoDB.

Answer (score 3):

`INSERT INTO table (fields) VALUES (values) WHERE condition`

Wait, what? Since when did `INSERT` allow `WHERE` clauses?

You either want to do an `UPDATE` or put that `client_id` in the fields to insert.

Comment: wow! lol! geez! never thought about that! sorry guys... mysql noob here.. it's just that I have never read that from anywhere.. my bad.

Answer (score 2):

An `INSERT` statement has no `WHERE` clause, as it is for creating *new* rows. We can assume you intended an `UPDATE` statement, since you wish to match an existing row:

```
UPDATE 
  clients 
SET water_bill_doc_url = 'client-uploads/01/water_bill.png' 
WHERE `client_id` = '74'
```

Review the [MySQL `UPDATE` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) for full details on the syntax.

Comment: thank you Mike! I really did not know what I was doing with the `INSERT` statement there.. geez!